# Sproutcore - Webkit appearance in searchfield

Tags: css, search, webkit, sproutcore

I am trying to create a search field with a Webkit appearance. But, I am getting around it. Here is how I create the searchField

```
mySearchView: SC.TextFieldView.design({
    layerId: 'searchView',
    layout: {height: 20, width: 120, centerY: 0, right: 240},
    hint: 'Search',
    classNames: ['searchField']
}),
```

and here the css part

```
.searchField { 
    background: none !important; 
    outline: none !important; 
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield !important; 
} 

.searchField input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.searchField input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button 
{ 
   -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button !important; 
} 

.searchField input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration { 
   -webkit-appearance: searchfield-decoration !important; 
} 

.searchField input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { 
   -webkit-appearance: searchfield-results-decoration !important; 
} 

.searchField input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button 
{ 
   -webkit-appearance: searchfield-results-button !important; 
}
```

But, it is not working. The best I could get is a rounded input field and a squared one overlapping. I can't even see whether the magnifier and the cancel buttons appear or not.
Has anybody got around getting that view? what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to give you such a bad news, but with SC up to 1.6 it will never work (at least with the stock SC.TextFieldView).
If you look at the [source](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.TextFieldView.html#doc=frameworks_foundation_views_text_field.js&src=true) code for SC.TextFieldView between lines 580 and 590 you will see that it is always rendered as a text field.
To be rendered as a search field the input type should be search.
Your only option is to provide a customized render method, but that, unfortunately, means duplicating lots of lines of code.